# Python: Sending over TCP session established from within a different class/thread

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, tcp, streaming

I have a python application which has two main functions. It takes in streaming data (lets call this the 'incoming data stream') from a remote source via a UDP listener thread.

There is also a TCP listener thread which listens for commands from another remote source. There are various commands implemented in the protocol but I am only implementing the 'send configuration data' (Which it does, and it works) and the START/STOP streaming data. This start/stop streaming data should forwarded the (encoded) 'incoming data stream' to the external TCP party.

I'm a bit of a novice Python user and have 'hacked' together what I have so far. Basically two threads, one constantly accepting the UDP streaming data (Rate: 10 messages per sec) and the other listening and handling the TCP requests. The way I have been planning this is to have a flag set when the TCP requests streaming data be STARTED, when this flag is True, the function which processes the incoming UDP data will send the formatted frame to the established TCP session.

The problem: I don't know how to reference or use the established TCP session outside the scope of its own operation. I.e. to send the config data to the established session from within the scope of the thread I have just used: 
`self.request.sendall(packedConfigFrame)`

Help much appreciated.

Code for reference: http://pastebin.com/PbCb59sy

Answer (score 0):

Might wanna try to use [deque](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#deque-objects), to create a global variable say

```
udpData = collections.deque()
```

Then store your UDP messages into udpData whenever you get them. And from the TCP thread, when your 'TCP requests streaming data' flag is True, call udpData, and consume data from it (you can pop data from either ends of the queue at your will), and then processes the UDP data and send the formatted frame to the established TCP session.

Comment: Good thinking. I have used deque before and didn't think of that for the incoming. 

My problem is, if my TCP Thread is instantiated to handle an incoming connection, how do I deal with the fact this data will be streaming '24/7' once requested. I don't want to put a loop in the 'request handler' thread - as it will also need to listen for a 'stop request'

Comment: I don't think you need to put another loop in the 'request handler'. Inside the Handle routine, you have a 'while' loop in your original code, and you when streaming is set True, you check if you have data in the 'udpData', if you do, you just pop one item out, and format it, and send it. And since that while loop is running all the time, so, if steaming is True and udpData has data, then it's supposed to be sending out the data.

Comment: With how it's currently setup; within the request handler, the while loop only iterates when TCP requests are received.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand your question a little better now. What if you set both of your threads as daemon by something liked    class T1(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, name='T1')
        self.daemon = True                                          And add a 'run' routine under each thread, and under               'if __name__ == '__main__':', you use a while loop, and start both threads. The Daemon setting would ensure the needed routines to be triggered when there are jobs for them to do...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean on 'run routine' do you mean an __init__ for the thread class? At the moment I have the 'handle(self)' under  the threads.
So at the moment the 'handle' of the TCP request handler waits for data before progressing to any further operations:
`def handle(self):  
        global streaming  
        while True:  
            print("PMU Command Received")  
            data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()  
            response = processC37Message(data)  
            if not response == None:  
                self.request.sendall(response)`